# Автоматический поиск картинок в интернете с помощью Python

Tags: python, изображения, google-search

У google и yandex есть сервисы для поиска картинок.  Каким образом можно реализовать такой поиск с помощью Python? Существуют ли готовые реализации?

Comment: Вы хотите узнать есть ли у google, yandex, etc API, которое вы из Питона можете вызвать?

Comment: Посмотрите это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242967/python-search-with-image-google-images

Comment: Поиск по картинке или по ключу?

Answer (score 0):

Если по ключу, то попробуйте:

```
import webbrowser

keys = ['котята', 'обои на рабочий стол', 'дональд трамп', 'not bad мем']
for key in keys:
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.google.ru/search?q='+ key +'&newwindow=1&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X')
```